# SimpleDateFormatter parsing is behaving Differently?

Tags: java

I am trying to get my head around how dates in java are getting parsed, and I still cant seem to get around to what I need to pass in as parameters to get a consistent output no matter what time zone I am in.

I wrote this test class:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;

public class TimeTest {

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{

    String dateString = "2012-03-28 11:45:00 +0200";
    String dateString1 = "2012-03-28 11:45:00 +0000";
    Timestamp timestamp= null;
    Timestamp timestamp1= null;
    DateFormat planningDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    Date date = planningDateFormat.parse(dateString);
    Date date1 = planningDateFormat.parse(dateString1);
    timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    timestamp1 = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
    System.out.println("Time value passed in was: " + dateString);
    System.out.println("Date value after parse: " + date);  
    System.out.println("Time stamp value is: " + timestamp);

    System.out.println("Time value passed in was: " + dateString1);
    System.out.println("Date value after parse: " + date1); 
    System.out.println("Time stamp value is: " + timestamp1);
}
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
Time value passed in was: 2012-03-28 11:45:00 +0200
Date value after parse: Wed Mar 28 10:45:00 IST 2012
Time stamp value is: 2012-03-28 10:45:00.0
Time value passed in was: 2012-03-28 11:45:00 +0000
Date value after parse: Wed Mar 28 12:45:00 IST 2012
Time stamp value is: 2012-03-28 12:45:00.0
```

Now let me explain why non of this makes any sense:

In the first date passes in I pass in the time 11:45 with a +0200 offset, and it gives me the time IST which is Irish Standard Time of 10:45.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on there and how its coming to this conclusion? The time passes in of 11:45, does that represent 11:45 UTC or 11:45 local time (to the country which has an offset of +0200). From what I see it seems to me that the time represents the local time.

Another question is:
If I'm in Ireland, which is +0000 in the winter and +0100 in the summer. Would the value being passed in for "Z" change depending on what date I'm querying? Or shouldn't java know this automatically depending on the date passes in with the time?

I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: Fair point but I'm dyslectic and sometimes even manage to get my words messed up, changed it now.

Comment: No worries. BTW, IMHO the guy who thought up the word dyslexic was a sadist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Z` in your format pattern represents an absolute offset from UTC. When you say `11:45:00 +0200`, that is equal to the time represented by `09:45:00 UTC`; i.e., 2 hours ahead of what the time is at UTC. Since IST is UTC+1 we have:

> `11:45:00 +0200` == `09:45:00 UTC` == `10:45:00 IST`

If you use a timezone alias (e.g., `Europe/Dublin`) instead of an absolute offset, Java will automatically handle daylight savings time rules depending on the date part you provide.

Comment: On my machine, at least, IST points to *India* so perhaps using the Olson ID would be better.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but where can I find a list of the timezone aliases accepted by Java? and I know its unrelated to the question but do you know how could I generate them using JavaScript (if such a way exists)? Because I want to be able to allow a user to select a time and date (which represent where ever he is) and then I need to pass in the timezone so the date and time get parsed correctly.

Comment: You can checkout [TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs()) to get the IDs supported by your JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the time passed in is local time. By saying `2012-03-28 11:45:00 +0200` you actually say "11:45 in a timezone which has +02:00 against UTC". The time is then, of course, shown in your local time (which is +01:00 against UTC because of the DST, so it subtracted one hour from the passed time).

The Date methods do respect Daylight saving time. Try changing your local system date and you'll see that the returned time also changes. Or try inputing CDT, CST, MDT, MST and similar timezome strings supported by Date class - they all know their Daylight saving time.

Comment: The Time/Dates are a huge mess in computer industry.

Comment: so if I want to pass in the Local time for Syria (11:45:00) I would have to pass in +0300 in the summer (because its +3 hrs from UTC int he summer)  and +0200 in the winter (when the time difference is only 2 hrs from UTC)? IS there any thing I can do to get around that? Can i pass in a offset or timezone value along with the date and time regardless of the location of the date (whether its summer or winter)